# groovy simple trait fail

Tags: groovy, jvm

I am learning groovy now. And in my case some simple code with trait is not working. 
Here's code:

```
trait Mark {
   void DisplayMarks() {
      println("Display Marks");
   } 
}


public class MarkOwner implements Mark { 
   int StudentID
   int Marks1;
   static void main(String[] args) {
       MarkOwner m = new MarkOwner();
       m.DisplayMarks();
   }
}
```

And here's error:

```
msangel@msangel-np6:~/work/groov$ groovy scr2.groovy 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/msangel/work/groov/scr2.groovy: 2: Method definition not expected here. Please define the method at an appropriate place or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead. at line: 2 column: 4. File: /home/msangel/work/groov/scr2.groovy @ line 2, column 4.
      void DisplayMarks() {
      ^

1 error
```

I was also looked to different tutorial but the syntax seems to be correct. 
Here s my default groovy version number:

```
msangel@msangel-np6:~/work/groov$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.8.0_91 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Comment: Traits where introduced in Groovy 2.3.  Do yourself a favour and don't use your distributions groovy version from the dark ages.  Get SDKMan and use a recent one.

Comment: I used `apt-get install groovy`.

Comment: Just don't.  Use http://sdkman.io/install.html instead. Or install on your own in a way your see fit. 1.8 is how old?  5 years?  We are at 2.4 right now.

Comment: a lot of answers on stackoverflow and serverfault are outdated and points this way of installing as correct one

Comment: It's not, use sdkman or do it manually if you want to use traits